# Repeating Tile Background pygame

Tags: python, opengl, pygame

Is there a feature similar to this in pygame?

```
screen.fill(pygame.image.load('brick.bmp').convert())
```

I would like to fill the window (background) with an image to produce an effect similar to this:

[image]

My only idea would be to blit each brick onto the screen, but i think that would slow down the game. Does anyone have an idea how to do this (and also provide some example code)?

Heres a snippet of a method that works but goes slow

```
    While True:
        for y in range(0,600,32):
            for x in range(0,800,32):
                screen.blit( self.img,(x,y))
        ...
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: You say in comments that this is "slower".   how much slower? how are you measuring this?

Comment: I have a player on screen that I can move with the arrow keys. When I put this code in, he moves slower.

Comment: Does the FPS change? This low resolution, and small number of tiles should be fast. Are all of your surfaces loaded, and converted, outside the draw loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> blit each brick onto the screen, but i think that would slow down the game.

Not as much as you probably think.  bliting is very fast.  Even if there were some sort of "fill" command, it would still amount to copying the image to a surface until the surface is covered.

If the background image is stationary, you can render to an off-screen surface when your program starts, and instead of erasing the screen by filling with a solid color, just blit the pre-rendered background instead.

Comment: Im using pygame.display.flip(), and I think its removing the bricks that ive created before the main loop. When I put the generated code in the main loop, its going slower but it works. How could i pre render?

Comment: flip doesn't erase the screen, it only reveals what you've drawn since the last time you flipped (kinda...)

Comment: if you are really worried about speed, *don't* use `pygame.display.flip()` -- that's a timekiller. only blit your updates (and "repair" the background wherer something moved away), and then only update the rects you changed. On a big surface and with few tiles, that can change performance *a lot*.

Comment: @kratenko: as pygame uses double buffer, if I don't use `pygame.display.flip()` I will never see anything that was drawn, so how to avoid using it?

Comment: @MestreLion For what I found in others' discussions, using double buffering is not worth the trouble in pygame (have no reference to back that up, nor any own experience on it - I'm not using pygame for my projects, since I need some gui support...). One flip per frame might be okay with your project, depending on what you are doing. But if you only update very few parts on a huge screen, using `update(rect_list)` is much faster. All will be different if you use opengl, I have never done that.

Comment: Actually, both `.display.flip()` and `display.update()` use double buffer. And they perform exactly the same unless you do pass the "dirty" `rect_list` to `update()`. When you originally said *"don't use `flip()`"* I assumed you meant *"use nothing at all"*. So I guess the full wording would be *"dont use `pygame.display.flip()`, use `pygame.display.update(rect_list)`"*

Answer (score 2):

I can't find this feature in Pygame. However, I have a way to improve the performence of your method.
You can create a surface first. Let's call it `bgSurface`. Then you blit all bricks to `bgSurface` using your double loop method. Then in the main loop, you do `screen.blit(bgSurface, (0, 0))`. Have a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have this really simple function that works on resizable windows too:

```
def tileBackground(screen: pygame.display, image: pygame.Surface) -> None:
    screenWidth, screenHeight = screen.get_size()
    imageWidth, imageHeight = image.get_size()
    
    # Calculate how many tiles we need to draw in x axis and y axis
    tilesX = math.ceil(screenWidth / imageWidth)
    tilesY = math.ceil(screenHeight / imageHeight)
    
    # Loop over both and blit accordingly
    for x in range(tilesX):
        for y in range(tilesY):
            screen.blit(image, (x * imageWidth, y * imageHeight))
```